# Adding a new row to DBTreeList at runtime

Tags: delphi, treelist

I'm a newbie to Delphi and coding itself and have an issue which I can't solve.

I have to create a `Treelist` based on values from a Database which I did in the design field, here is an example on how it looks:
[image] . Now it needs to be able to insert a new row after giving it a description (which is labeled as 'bez') while running.

The most obvious way to do that in my mind is to right click on a parent field and be able to add a new child field, how can I achieve that?

Also at the end of a parent tree I need it to be able to open a script/file, is that possible too?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I didn't coded anything yet, the code contains only the auto generated uses and types while adding components to forms and binding the database to it

Comment: Which DB components do you use?

Comment: Please add your `.dfm` file to your post.

Comment: If it's attached to a dataset (the *DB* part of the name), then the way to make changes of any kind to the data is to do so in the dataset. To add a row, add a row to the dataset. To delete a row, delete that row in the dataset. Data-bound controls always respond to changes in the dataset itself.